# How to automatize this process?

Tags: bash

Hello everyone I am writing a script to parse some parameters in bash, I would like to run my code as follows:

```
bash myScript.sh +value value1 +valuei value2 ... +valuek valuer
```

and with that flags create variables to store that parameters as follows:

```
variable1=value
variable2=value1
variable3=value
variable4=value2
.
.
.
valriabler= valriablem
```

note, I just want to save the the value of the flag by removing the + symbol as in the previous examples, in order to achieve this I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable1=$(echo $1 | cut -d "+" -f 2)
variable2=$2
echo $variable1
echo $variable2
```

and after I ran it, I got:

```
bash myScript.sh +hola hi
hola
hi
```

I could parse the first two parameters, but the problem is that I want to do it for multiple variables:

```
myScript +value value1 +valuei value2 ... +valuek valuer
```

I would like to appreciate any help about how to automatize? this task, I am going to parse multiple arguments that come in pairs with the same structure, I want to store their values in variables, I would like to appreciative any suggestion of how to achieve this.
Note, I want to avoid using getopts since I want to use complex flags.

Comment: Please do not edit your question and edit your code, which invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array, and do it like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
while (( $# )); do
   arr+=("${1#+}")
   shift
done
```

You assign the next variable to the next element, shift it off, and continue if there is more.  You can echo them out like this.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Your suggestion is pretty fine but I already was able to parse the variables I added my own answer.

Comment: @user138717 so, the question is not whether you updated your OP an hour after I provided an answer-- but what ELSE are you still looking for?

Comment: @user138717 do you not realize that by switching to an array like I wrote, would let you do this for any number of arguments?  Which is what you said your approach lacked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that any Bourne Shell supports one-shot-assignments with prefixing the command by the variable assignments?

```
variable1=value variable2=val2 variable3=val3 myscript args ...
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great suggestion but I want to avoid writing that assignments in the command line.

Comment: @user138717 How is this different from what you say in your last snippet: `myScript +value value1 ...` The only difference is that you rearrange the words of the command. If that is not what you want, maybe you can clarify and describe your actual problem?

Comment: Why? This is pretty much *exactly* why environment variables exist.

Comment: This doesn't address removing the `+'.  Since that's a requirement, I'm guessing the script is being called where the number of values being passed is unknown and uncontrolled-- so it can't be hard coded before calling the script.

Comment: @SaintHax I believe it is helpful to think outside the box. The + issue may become a non-issue if the OP is shown a way he didn't think of. Which is why I asked him for clarification.

Comment: Thanks that is a very good suggestion however I would like to find a way to parse the argument's as I explain in the description, I need to run my script as follows: myScript +value value1 +valuei value2 ... +valuek valuer

Comment: @user138717 I'm still bewildered why you've ignored my answer that meets your requirements?  At least leave a comment, b/c I'm personally insulted by this point.

Answer (score -1):

This is a way to achieve the parsing of the arguments, this script produce a csv with the property value of the variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch archive.csv
while (($# >= 1))
do
        echo "$(echo $1| tr -d "+"),$2" >> archive.csv
        shift 2
done

cat archive.csv
```

I can run this like:

```
bash parse.sh +value value1 +valuei value2
```

and I get:

```
value,value1
valuei,value2
```

which is fine in order to parse the arguments.

Comment: You took my loop, and then echo'd the pair on one line to a file-- which was not a requirement?  I think I'm being trolled.

Comment: well the structure of a loop it's not your invention, the condition it's pretty different, and I had to use two shifts, I also used the >> operator and the tr to clean the arguments, I think that it´s pretty different than yours.